# adjusting for a binary confounder of a continuous predictor in a glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, confounding

I would like to predict the chance of receiving a blood transfusion based on hemoglobin level of a patient (hemoglobin continuous, blood transfusion categorical).
I found that patients with low hemoglobin have a some background diseases that those with high hemoglobin don't.

How do I practically adjust for the confounder "background disease - True or false" in a glm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the second variable to your glm as a binary variable. If you were doing it in R you would change your formula from `blood_trans ~ hemo` to `blood_trans ~ hemo + disease`. For this model you would interpret the coefficient for the hemoglobin level as the the effect on blood transfusion after controlling for the effect of the background disease.